# Proper Table naming convention for a many-to-many intersect table

Tags: database-design

I have a many to many relation for: Client and Broker tables (just an example). Obviously, each client can have multiple brokers and each broker can have multiple clients. What is considered the proper naming convention for the intersect table.... is it ClientBroker...?

Comment: Although it's for sure not a convention, I like to call those things `broker2client` in private applications. This way, I can visually quickly find tables that only connect other tables. Just from the name `ClientBroker` or `client_broker` it's not clear to me what it contains. It might be clients which are brokers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I usually use the names of both of the joining tables.

So, in your case, ClientBroker.

Comment: It's also good to order the tables in the name alphabetically! Some frameworks (laravel) use this notation. i.e. `BrokerClient` instead

Answer (score 80):

I would prefer "Clients_Brokers" (pluralizing both names to indicate many-to-many).

Comment: I voted this up since someone else voted it down. I think this convention is fine and often necessary. Some ORM libraries provided by MVC frameworks have a naming convention for tables to handle relationships automatically. I know of at least 3 PHP frameworks that use plural name and underscore separation for many-to-many pivot table names like this.

Comment: This is the old singular vs. plural table naming conflict (extended here to join tables). Do you name a table in the singular - e.g. "Customer" because each record represents one Customer? Or plural because the table itself contains many "Customers"? It's a matter of opinion, I don't think there's a reason to downvote this.

Answer (score 28):

I prefer to distinguish between intersect tables and actual transactional tables. 
So, I end them with Map. So it would be Client_Broker_Map, or ClientBrokerMap.

Answer (score 12):

Some programmers don't like pluralizing table names for a few reasons:

- it breaks the "is a" rule, meaning if you have a table called 'User', then each record in the table "is a" User object. This follows object-orientation rules.
- a Model class is usually named for the table where its data comes from. So if you have a User model, the record represented by the model is in the User table

This makes a lot of sense if you're in control of the entire db and business layers of the project. However, a lot of frameworks now have ORM libraries that facilitate working with tables and relationships. Those ORM libraries often have a naming syntax that should be followed to let the ORM library do most of the heavy lifting.

For example, I use the Kohana MVC framework for PHP which offers an ORM library. The ORM suggests pluralizing table names, using all lowercase names, and using underscores for many-to-many table names. So for your example, you'd have the following tables: clients, brokers, and brokers_clients (the ORM suggests alphabetically arranging table names for many-to-many tables). When creating models for these tables (extending the ORM model), you use the singular value of the table name, so the model for clients would be Client. The ORM handles the pluralization conversion. Kohana's ORM also uses an inflection library, so unusual pluralization values are handled correctly. For example, a table named 'categories' can use the model name 'Category'. Finally, if you have a db structure already implemented but want to use the ORM library, you can override the default ORM table naming syntax and give it the table name you want to use.

Answer (score 11):

I've often seen the format "Client_Broker"

Comment: +1: Punctuation should be used sparingly, and in this case it helps distinguish the two sides.

Answer (score 10):

I am just in the middle of a project where i am getting table and field names using DESCRIBE. I'd use Client_x_Broker so I can easly find a table and get the fields by using `_x_` as a criteria, a string which is centainly not going to occure naturally in code or datasets, well not in mine anyway, and is easy to strp out to find the names of the single tables. Further, as long as i am consistent, i can get a lot of information just from the table name including the Primary Key names. Sorry for a, being late and b, going on. :)

Comment: I'll probably go with this one. Considering both table and model names. `ClientsBrokers` model? Not that bad, probably. And when you instantiate it? `clients_brokers`? What would be the plural form? `ClientBrokerMap` is slightly better. But even better is `ClientBrokerRelationship`, if you ask me. And `ClientXBroker` is a nice way contract that.

Comment: @x-yuri Why would you need a model for your pivot table? Presumably you would have a Client model and a Broker model, but I don't see the point of having ClientsBrokers model.

Comment: @Mike Where would you put data regarding the relationship? Take a look at example from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @x-yuri Ah, I see what you mean now. I'm relatively new to learning MVC and currently learning Laravel. Laravel handles pivot tables a bit differently (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Essentially on one model you define a `hasMany` relationship to the other model and on the other model you define a `belongsToMany` relationship to the first model. So as far as I can tell there's no need to create an actual pivot table model.

Comment: First, you use `belongsToMany` at both ends, `hasMany` is for one-to-many relationships. Then, you [don't have to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) define intermediate model in Django when you don't need it. And by the way, you specify relationship only at one end. "It doesn’t matter which model has the ManyToManyField, but you should only put it in one of the models – not both."

Answer (score 5):

For **Hibernate** users, there is undocumented rule found by trial and error based on log messages and analyzing generated queries:

[image]

Formalizing this picture, you need to use a linking table named : table1_table2 and use ids in linking table like these ones: table1_table1Id and table2_table2Id

By doing so, Hibernate understand what's going on without further explanation and providing @JoinTable info.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long courseId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="class")
    private String className;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Course> course;
}
```

If you stick to this mapping, all the JPQL queries work smoothly and as expected generating correct SQL queries with outer joins... Note, *course* without **-s** at the end! If you want course**s** anyways you should change fields name in joining table to table2**s**_table2Id and table itself to table2**s**

**P.S.** I haven't found any straightforward mentioning about this convention neither in JPA nor in Hibernate documentation (only in single [example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many)), and it can probably be changed in future releases, tested with Hibernate 5.2/5.3. However it gives a hint of how to name joining table and fields in it.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer junction table names that explain the relationship between the entities in the table. In this instance, I would either call the table "client_has_broker" or "broker_has_client".

Aside from making it clear what the relationship is (things like "client_broker" and "broker_x_client" don't tell you *how* the entities are related - does the client work with the broker, or did the client eat the broker?), this allows you to have other junction tables that relate the same entities in different ways - like, "client_hates_broker", or "broker_bankrupted_client".

As for the singular-vs.-plural issue - even though this is a many-to-many relationship, each row in the table still only refers to a single relationship, so I always use singular names (e.g. "client_has_broker", not "clients_have_brokers"). That way the name makes sense no matter how many results you get from a query. ("This client has these 5 client_has_broker relationships" makes more sense to me than "this client has these 5 clients_to_brokers relationships".)

Obviously there are a million different approaches - and I've tried a bunch of them - but for me, this has been been the easiest and clearest naming convention.